# I (unintentionally) deleted (I guess) a passwd file

Tags: password, crash, passwd-file

I was trying to install x11vnc to screen share my laptop through the terminal. While I was doing it, x11vnc asked me to add a password and so I did. Then I needed to open another terminal and it started with `"I have no name!"@laptop`, so I thought a restart should help.

I restarted the laptop and only this appears

```
/dev/****: clean, ****/*** files, ***/*** blocks
```

I rebooted a couple of times but it was the same.

I thought it had to do with the password of x11vnc, so I used the **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** to go to recovery mode and using a root shell I was trying to recover the (I believe) deleted `/etc/passwd` file.

But now it's still the same, I can't even use the `/var/backups/passwd.bak` as it says it doesn't exist.

Is there a way to recover some of my files? Or reinstall Ubuntu and not loose my files like in Windows? I have some valuable info for my thesis and clearly no time to do it again.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu live CD, press "Try Ubuntu", and go copy your thesis somewhere safe, like cloud storage. DO NOT copy it to the live CD, as the live CD is reset every time you reboot. Once your thesis is safe in the cloud, _then_ try to fix your issue.

Comment: @cocomac - I think you should post as an answer - it is what the OP is asking and you've answered with exactly what they need to get their data back.

Comment: You might have a backup copy of the password-file in `/etc/passwd-` from before the last password change / user add / user delete operation.

Comment: @cocomac I don't really remember if I click the option of encrypt my SSD. But I do remember all my passwords. Could it work out?